# How to access methods from C# dll using ctypes?

Tags: c#, python, .net, dll, python.net

I'm in a bit over my head here and have never worked with dll's before so hopefully my question makes sense.

I'm trying to use a C# dll that has a bunch of different classes in it. I've read other questions on here that show example code such as:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibary('pathToDLL')
lib.foo()
```

I understand that much. I haven't been able to figure out how to use methods that are in the classes in the dll if that makes sense. So if the dll contains a class called "Foo" with a method "bar" how do I call bar using ctypes? Also is ctypes the best way to try to access this dll or should I be using something else?

Comment: I believe since you want to use a C# (.NET) dll you will *not* be able to use ctypes as you would with regular dlls.  [pythonnet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonnet/2.2.1) may help you here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use pythonnet module for this.
Here is how it will work on windows.

1. Install : `pip install pythonnet`
2. Usage:

e.g.

```
# dll name  = mydll.dll
# namespace = mynamespace
# class     = Foo
# method    = bar

import clr
 # provide name without .dll and make sure either to 
 # copy the dll in pythonpath e.g. (c:\\python27) or add the path in 
 # sys.path
clr.AddReference("mydll")
import mynamespace
obj = mynamespace.Foo()
obj.bar()
```

Comment: Great. Let me know if you can make it to work on MAC. As the pythonnet is not getting installed on mac for me.

Comment: @Nitin_k29 for mac follow these instructions: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX#osx-notes